# What are the options for a REST API for .Net 3.5 stack

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5

I am currently on the .Net 3.5 stack (including VS2008 tooling) and will not be upgrading anytime soon. What options are available to me in order to create a restful API that will be consumed by my own web application. I see my options as:

- MVC2 (less of a choice as the team is not comfortable with it)
- WCF with HTTP toolkit. (not sure what version I should be looking at for my stack)

I need the following features:

- Authentication via cookies (I quite like the ActionFilter approach of MVC for this)
- Authorization on a resource    basis (User, account, etc. Again, I    like the AF approach to this)
- Everything runs under HTTPS

My uncertainty is what versions, etc do I look at for my stack and what are the arguments for and against each?

Comment: Why is your team not comfortable with MVC2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options:

- [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
- A [HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) (pretty low level though as you have to do all restful stuff yourself)
- [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta)
- [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) (.NET 4.0 only afaik)
- [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) (If you are basically exposing a database as a REST service)

A few more I have found on the web but know nothing about:

- [Snooze](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/snooze)
- [Siesta](http://kohari.org/2009/08/10/siesta-painless-rest-via-asp-net-mvc/) (Builds on top of ASP.NET MVC)
- [Bistro](http://bistroframework.org/index.php?title=Bistro_Framework_Home)

You can use MVC directly but keep in mind that is is not designed as a REST framework so doesn't thinks like content negotiation for you. You would have to build that yourself. Depending on what you are trying to do that might be a lot of work or it might be quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at [Mindtouch Dream](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/Dream): is a very mature Rest server and client library. Some points

- It has a very good support for async services
- can work with .net 3.5 or mono.
- the last version can also  be integrated with Asp Mvc (optional, its completety independent from asp).
- its on [github](https://github.com/MindTouch/DReAM)

(I'm not sure about if it will meet your Authentication / Authorization needs)